# How to update a subitem in a json file using jq?

Tags: json, updates, jq

Using `jq` I tried to update this json document:

```
{
"git_defaults": {
    "branch": "master",
    "email": "jenkins@host",
    "user": "Jenkins"
},
"git_namespaces": [
{
    "name": "NamespaceX",
        "modules": [
            "moduleA",
            "moduleB",
            "moduleC",
            "moduleD"
        ]
},
{
    "name": "NamespaceY",
    "modules": [
        "moduleE"
    ]
}
]
}
```

with adding `moduleF` to `NamespaceY`. I need to write the file back again to the original source file.

I came close (but no cigar) with:

```
jq  '. | .git_namespaces[] | select(.name=="namespaceY").modules |= (.+ ["moduleF"])' config.json
```

and

```
jq '. | select(.git_namespaces[].name=="namespaceY").modules |= (.+ ["moduleF"])' config.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following filter should perform the update you want:

```
(.git_namespaces[] | select(.name=="NamespaceY").modules) += ["moduleF"]
```

Note that the initial '.|' in your attempt is not needed; that "NamespaceY" is capitalized in config.json; that the parens as shown are the keys to success; and that += can be used here.

One way to write back to the original file would perhaps be to use 'sponge'; other possibilities are discussed on the jq FAQ https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ

Comment: I took it a small bit further: 
(.git_namespaces[] | select(.name=="NamespaceY").modules) |= (.+ ["moduleF"] | unique) 
to make sure its dont results in double entries